# Broke Apache after trying to link mysqld.service

Tags: apache, fedora, mysql

On my fedora server, any time I would reboot apache, I'd have to manually restart mysqld afterwards. I read that this could be fixed by creating a link with:

```
    ln -s '/usr/lib/systemd/system/mysqld.service' '/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/mysqld.service'
```

After entering this command and restarting Apache, it won't load and is in a failed state.

```
    httpd.service - The Apache HTTP Server
    Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service; enabled)
    Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2015-02-15 17:21:22          EST; 6s ago
    Process: 3904 ExecStop=/usr/sbin/httpd $OPTIONS -k graceful-stop (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
    Process: 3902 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/httpd $OPTIONS -DFOREGROUND (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
    Status: "Total requests: 8; Current requests/sec: 0; Current traffic:   0 B/sec"

    Feb 15 17:21:22 pbcja httpd[3902]: httpd: Syntax error on line 356 of /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf: Syntax error on line 22 of /etc/httpd/conf.d/ph.../IfModule>
    Feb 15 17:21:22 pbcja systemd[1]: httpd.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
    Feb 15 17:21:22 pbcja httpd[3904]: httpd: Syntax error on line 356 of /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf: Syntax error on line 22 of         /etc/httpd/conf.d/ph.../IfModule>
    Feb 15 17:21:22 pbcja systemd[1]: httpd.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
    Feb 15 17:21:22 pbcja systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
    Feb 15 17:21:22 pbcja systemd[1]: Unit httpd.service entered failed state.
```

What do I do to fix this? Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Maybe this should be asked on Server Fault? http://serverfault.com/